# cant remove some chareter in string, even regex not working, its matching in online tools but not working in code

Tags: node.js, regex, string, replace, aws-lambda

My string is like:

`"Drop Name,Area/zone,Pop,Hub,Gstinnumber\r\nCOCO000007,coco000007,coco000007,KAB STAR,Active,12-04-2017 12:00,\"2A GOUR GHOSH ROAD, KOLKATA-700025\",West Bengal,Kolkata,700025"`

and I want to replace this `\r\n`, with comma (`,`), so I did like this

`a=a.replace('/\\r\\n/g', ' ');`

even I tried to do `a.split('/\\r\\n/g', ' ');`
but result is the same, no change.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that the regex is quoted, so the pattern you are passing a string instead of a regex. Do it without quotes:

```
a = a.replace(/\r\n/g, ',')
```